# How do I set the color of an NSButtonCell text label

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How do I set the color of an NSButtonCell's label (title) text, that is the column cell for a table view? In my case, it is an checkbox button cell. (Is it possible using IB?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one,, i think its perfect one.

```
NSColor *color = [NSColor redColor];
NSMutableAttributedString *colorTitle =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[button attributedTitle]];

NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(0, [colorTitle length]);

[colorTitle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:color
                   range:titleRange];

[button setAttributedTitle:colorTitle];
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try an attributed string value.

```
NSColor *txtColor = [NSColor redColor];
NSFont *txtFont = [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
NSDictionary *txtDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        txtFont, NSFontAttributeName, txtColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[[NSAttributedString alloc]
        initWithString:@"Hello!" attributes:txtDict] autorelease];
[[attrStrTextField cell] setAttributedStringValue:attrStr];
[attrStrTextField updateCell:[attrStrTextField cell]];
```

Comment: You can pass `0.0` for the size to get the default regular size. You can also ask NSFont for any of the other sizes (e.g., the size for Small controls and cells). You generally should not pass an explicit size.